# opencart как удалить функционал который не нужен?

Tags: php, opencart

Как правильно на чистом opencart полностью убрать стандартный checkout?

Comment: Поставить модуль для одностраничного оформления заказа, использовать фреймворки

Comment: http://simpleopencart.com/

Answer (score 0):

Если делать самому то нужно будет перелопатить файлы контроллеров из catalog/controller/checkout и файлы темы catalog/view/theme/ВАША_ТЕМА/template/checkout. 
При этом нужно понимать как работать с сессиями в OC.

Можно полезности почитать во тут https://webocreation.com/blog/opencart-tutorial/

Но если нет желания сильно морочиться то конечно же https://simpleopencart.com